# Pythonic way to iterate over multiple list to remove elements before working on the new list

Tags: python

I have a list class with values as shown representing nodes in a graph.

```
List x= [5, 1, 2, 4]
        [5, 1, 2, 4]
        [5, 1, 2, 4]
        [5, 1, 2, 4]
```

How do I delete 1st element from 1st list, 2nd from 2nd list 3rd from 3rd list etc and then use each of the remaining list for plotting the graph. i.e I will get 4 different plots. I expect to get :

```
NewList x= [1, 2, 4]
           [5, 2, 4]
           [5, 1, 4]
           [5, 1, 2]
```

Here is the start of my Code.

```
tG = G.copy()
orderToRemoveNodes = 5,1,2,4
myNodes = 1, 2, 4 ,5
    for n in mynodes:
        e = removedNode
        setRemoved = [list(x) for x in set(map(frozenset, e))]
        res = list(map(int, orderToRemoveNodes))
        for i in res:
            if i == n:
                tG.remove_node(i)
                tG.add_edges_from(setRemoved)
                nx.draw(tG)
                plt.show()
```

Here is the output of print(type(res))

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

To be sincere, I am not sure how to proceed. The only part I need is how to iterate over the lists one element after another for each subsequent list.Thank you

Comment: basically u are trying to get NewList as ur output right ?

Comment: like i don't know the background use but i can code for u a method that takes in x as input and would give u newList x as output

Comment: yes but the elements eliminated are different in each list

Comment: that's fine, i know how to handle that

Comment: can u also provide ur code till now ?

Comment: my code is a lot so just picked a part of it but basically I am planning to plot each list which are connected nodes

Comment: People with power to just down vote without explanation is bad for learning

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
big_list = [[5, 1, 2, 4],
            [5, 1, 2, 4],
            [5, 1, 2, 4],
            [5, 1, 2, 4]]
```

and want to remove the 0th index of the 0th list, the 1st of the 1st, the 2nd of the 2nd and so on...

```
[[el for i, el in enumerate(sublst) if i != j] for j, sublst in enumerate(big_list)]
```

Which will give:

```
result = [[   1, 2, 4],
          [5,    2, 4],
          [5, 1,    4],
          [5, 1, 2   ]]
```

Comment: That is what i want yes but I tried and I got int object is not iterable

Comment: @jackpetes then your input doesn't match the spec in your question, *shrug*

Comment: @jackpetes that doesn't help, sorry. If `res` is a list of lists of ints, this code should work (where you replace `big_list` with `res`), but it looks like `res` is something entirely strange. Is this something custom you've built that isn't behaving normally?

Comment: That was exactly what I did but got the error. The above code does make sense but I am not sure whats wrong. res is a list of return from a function call. Is there any other way to find the type instead of using print(type)?